# Prove that for any integer $a$, $9\nmid(a^2-3)$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, divisibility, integers

I'd like to know if my proof is a valid way of proving this and additionally if there is a better way of going about this? I'm relatively new to discrete mathematics so any critique would be very helpful for me to improve my style and general way of going about these proofs.

**Proof:**

Suppose not. That is, suppose $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $9\mid(a^2-3)$. By definition of divisibility, $a^2-3=9p$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}$. By the quotient-remainder theorem, $a$ can be written in one of the forms
$$3q\text{ or }3q+1\text{ or }3q+2$$
for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$.

**Case 1 ($a=3q$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$):** Since $a=3q$,
$$a^2-3=(3q)^2-3=9q^2-3=9p\Rightarrow9(q^2-p)=3\Rightarrow3(q^2-p)=1\text{.}$$
$q^2-p\in\mathbb{Z}\because\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and multiplication but $q^2-p=1/3\notin\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow$ a contradiction.

**Case 2 ($a=3q+1$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$):** Since $a=3q+1$,
$$a^2-3=(3q+1)^2-3=9q^2+6q-2=9p\Rightarrow3(3q^2+2q-3p)=2\text{.}$$
$3q^2+2q-3p\in\mathbb{Z}\because\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and multiplication but $3q^2+2q-3p=2/3\notin\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow$ a contradiction.

**Case 3 ($a=3q+2$ for some $q\in\mathbb{Z}$):** Since $a=3q+2$,
$$a^2-3=(3q+2)^2-3=9q^2+12q+1=9p\Rightarrow3(3q^2+4q-3p)=-1\text{.}$$
$3q^2+4q-3p\in\mathbb{Z}\because\mathbb{Z}$ is closed under addition and multiplication but $3q^2+4q-3p=-1/3\notin\mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow$ a contradiction.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Answer (score 5):

One way is to observe that $$a^2-3 = 9p \implies a^2 = 3(3p+1) \implies 3|a^2 \implies 3|a\implies a=3q.$$
Then you use the reasoning you mentioned for Case 1.

Answer (score 3):

It is correct, but you can merge cases 2 and 3 into a single one. If $a=3q\pm1$, then$$a^2-3=9q^2\pm6q+1-3=9q^2\pm6q-2,$$which is not a multiple of $3$ and therefore it is not a multiple of $9$.

Answer (score 2):

More simply if for absurd:

$$a^2-3 \equiv 0 \pmod{9}$$
$$a^2 \equiv 3 \pmod{9}$$

But the quadratic residues modulo $9$ are $[0,1,4,7]$ so this is absurd.

:)

Comment: This  is solving the problem by knowing the answer! The problem is exactly  to show that $3$ is not a quadratic residue mod $9$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich No. This is solving a trivial problem. Nothing more nothing less. I just used a number theory tool.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich but that is trivial, just run through all possibilities. I don't think this is a useless answer since it reduces the problem to a finite verification.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ 3\!+\!9n = 3(1\!+\!3n)\,$ isn't a *square* since $3$ occurs to *odd* power $(= 1),\,$ by $\,3\nmid 1\!+\!3n$

Comment: This assumes you already know FTA (or, more simply, that every integer $n > 0$ can be written *uniquely* in the form $\,3^j k\, $ where $\, 3\nmid k),\ $ so squares must have an $ even$ power of $3$. Though we can prove it more directly, this highlights the close relationship with irrationality proofs of sqrts and related results.

Answer (score 1):

To be divisible by $9$, $a^2-3$ need to be divisible by $3$. For any integer $a$, $a^2\equiv 0,1\pmod{3}$.

If $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{3}$, we have $a^2-3\equiv1\pmod{3}$, means $3\nmid(a^2-3)$ and hence $9\nmid(a^2-3)$.

So, we have $a^2\equiv 0\pmod{3}$ the only possibility left. As, $3|a^2\implies 3|a$, use the arguments from case 1 of your solution.